# When using the gson library for converting a Scala class to a string, UTF-8 characters are not escaped

Tags: scala, utf-8, gson, escaping

I am trying to convert an instance of a Scala class to a string in Json format, using the Gson library. However, UTF-8 characters are not escaped anymore after the conversion. The code looks like this:

```
case class exampleClass(exampleString: String)
val myClass = exampleClass("this = cool")

val gson = new Gson()
val myString = gson.toJson(myClass)

println(myClass.exampleString)
println(myString)
```

The output of this code (see the println statements) looks like this:

```
this = cool
{"exampleString": "this \u003d cool"}
```

I do not understand why the "="-statement is not escaped in the output string after applying the toJson method. I am very new to Scala so probably the answer is quite straightforward, but I have yet to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below solution:

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder

case class exampleClass(exampleString: String)
val myClass = exampleClass("this = cool")

val myString = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping.create.toJson(Test("this = cool"))

println(myString)
```